# Link List of Class, How to get call toString while Transversing?

Tags: c++, list, class, hyperlink

I was wondering how I could call the `toString()` method in my Link List of the class `BoxClass`. `BoxClass` has a `double` `length`, `width` and `height`.

**my BoxClass:**

```
class BoxClass{
private:
    double length;
    double width;
    double height;

public:
    // Default constructor w/ no parameters
    BoxClass(){
        length = 0;
        width = 0;
        height = 0;
    }

    // Constructor with arguments
    BoxClass(double boxLength, double boxWidth, double boxHeight){
        length = boxLength;
        width = boxWidth;
        height = boxHeight;
    }

    // Setters and Getters
    void setLength(double boxLength){
        length = boxLength;
    }
    double getLength(){
        return length;
    }

    void setWidth(double boxWidth){
        width = boxWidth;
    }
    double getWidth(){
        return width;
    }

    void setHeight(double boxHeight){
        height = boxHeight;
    }
    double getHeight(){
        return height;
    }

    // Returns the volume of the boxes
    double Volume(){
        return (length * width * height);
    }

    // toString method for boxes, returns "(length) x (width) x (height) string
    string toString(){
        return ("(" + to_string(length)+ "x" + to_string(width) + "x" + to_string(height) + ")");
    }
}; // End of BoxClass() class
```

**LinkNode.h**

```
//Template ListNode class definition.
#ifndef LINKNODE_H
#define LINKNODE_H

template <typename T> class LinkList;

template <typename T> class LinkNode{
friend class LinkNode <T>; 
public:
    LinkNode(const T &); 
    T getData()const;
    T data;
    LinkNode <T> *nextPtr;
};

template <typename T> LinkNode <T>::LinkNode(const T &info):data(info), nextPtr(NULL){
    // Empty body
}

template <typename T>T LinkNode<T>::getData()const{
    return data;
}

#endif
```

**Main (Creating the class, adding it to Link List**

```
//  Create the Box class
    BoxClass userBox(length, width, height);

//  Add box class to Link List
    Box.insertNode(userBox);

    Box.print();
```

**LinkList.h print() method**

```
template<typename T>void LinkList<T>::print()const {
// To list off nodes
int counter = 1;

if (isEmpty()) {
    cout << "No boxes in list!\n";
} else {
    LinkNode<T>*currentPtr = firstPtr;

    cout << "Your boxes in increasing order of volume is:\n";
    //      while (currentPtr) {
    while (currentPtr != NULL) {

        //      Output as "#. (length x width x height)
                cout << counter << ". " << currentPtr->data << endl;
        printf("  %i. %.2f\n", counter, currentPtr->data);
        currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
        counter++;
    }
}
}
```

**LinkList.h**

```
//Template LinkList class definition.
#ifndef LINKLIST_H
#define LINKLIST_H
#include <iostream>
#include "LinkNode.h"
using namespace std;

template<typename T> class LinkList {
public:
    LinkList();
    void addNode(const T &);
    void insertNode(const T &);
    bool isEmpty() const;
    void print() const;

private:
    LinkNode<T>*firstPtr;
    LinkNode<T>*getNewNode(const T &);
};

template<typename T>LinkList<T>::LinkList() :firstPtr(NULL) {
// Empty body
}

template <typename T>void LinkList<T>::insertNode(const T &value) {
LinkNode<T>*newPtr = getNewNode(value);
bool inserted = false;

if (isEmpty() || (newPtr->data < firstPtr->data)) {
    newPtr->nextPtr = firstPtr;
    firstPtr = newPtr;
    //      cout << "  " << newPtr->data << " inserted at front of list.\n";
    printf("  %.2f inserted at front of list.\n", newPtr->data);
} else {
    LinkNode<T>*currentPtr = firstPtr;
    while (currentPtr->nextPtr && !inserted) {
        if (newPtr->data < currentPtr->nextPtr->data) { 
            //      cout << " " << newPtr->data << " inserted before " << currentPtr->nextPtr->data << ". " << endl;
            printf("  %.2f inserted before %.2f.\n", newPtr->data, currentPtr->nextPtr->data);
            newPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
            currentPtr->nextPtr = newPtr;
            inserted = true;
        } else {
            currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
        }
    }
    if (!inserted) {
        currentPtr->nextPtr = newPtr;
        printf("  %.2f inserted at the end of list.\n", newPtr->data);
    }
}
}

template<typename T>bool LinkList<T>::isEmpty()const {
return firstPtr == NULL;
}

template<typename T>LinkNode<T>*LinkList<T>::getNewNode(const T &value) {
return new LinkNode<T>(value);
}

template<typename T>void LinkList<T>::print()const {
// To list off nodes
int counter = 1;

if (isEmpty()) {
    cout << "No boxes in list!\n";
} else {
    LinkNode<T>*currentPtr = firstPtr;

    cout << "Your boxes in increasing order of volume is:\n";
    //      while (currentPtr) {
    while (currentPtr != NULL) {

        //      Output as "#. (length x width x height)
                cout << counter << ". " << currentPtr->data << endl;
        printf("  %i. %.2f\n", counter, currentPtr->data);
        currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
        counter++;
    }
}
}

#endif
```

So again, my question is- How do I go about traversing the list and calling the `toString()` BoxClass method? I tried everything from `cout << data.toString() << endl;` but that doesn't work. I've been stuck on this for days, can someone help me out?

edit: added LinkList.h

Comment: Basically, your implementation is missing the concept of an `iterator`.  From outside the linked list, I should be able to say "get me the first node", then "get me the next node" and loop on that.  Yes, internally you can do this *within* the list now, but publicly, it can't be done.  So this is what you need to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your implementation of `LinkList<T>` class has no way for the client code to go through each node of the list in a loop.  What if we don't want to print, but do something else with each box?

In addition, it would look weird if I have a `LinkList<Widget>`, and I see the text when I call `print()`:

**"Your boxes in increasing order of volume is:";**

I would say, "what boxes? what volume?  I have Widgets, not boxes".

A more complete implementation would look something like this (caveat: This has not been compiled.  It is to give you the gist of what you should be doing):

```
template<typename T> class LinkList {
public:
    LinkList();
    void addNode(const T &);
    void insertNode(const T &);
    bool isEmpty() const;

    // this is what you're missing from the current implementation
    typedef LinkNode<T>* Iterator;
    Iterator begin() { return firstPtr; }
    Iterator next(Iterator ptr) { return ptr->nextPtr; }
    Iterator end() { return NULL; }  

private:
    LinkNode<T>* firstPtr;
    LinkNode<T>* getNewNode(const T &);
};
```

Then with this, the `print` function need not be part of the linked list.  It can live on the outside:

```
LinkList<BoxClass> boxList;
//...
void print() 
{
    if (boxList.isEmpty()) 
        cout << "No boxes in list!\n";
    else
    {
       int counter = 1;
       cout << "Your boxes in increasing order of volume is:\n";

       // get first box
       LinkList<BoxClass>::Iterator curBox = boxList.begin();

       // loop until no more boxes 
       while (curBox != boxList.end())
       {
            // now use curBox to do whatever you want with this box
            BoxClass& b  = curBox->getData();  
            cout << counter << ". " << b.toString();

            // go to the next box
            curBox = boxList.next(curBox);
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Note how `print` is no longer a member of `LinkList`.  Also, note the `typedef` to give us a "nice" name for the `LinkNode` pointer that the client uses.  The comments should be self-explanatory.

I didn't want to overcomplicate the code by introducing a "real" iterator (i.e. overloaded `++`), but that operator would replace the `LinkList<T>:::next()` function call.  I leave that to you as an additional exercise.

Answer (score 2):

When you write `template <typename T> class LinkNode{` you are specifically stating that your node class will have no built-in knowledge of the type of the node that it contains.

You have not shown us your `LinkList<T>` class, but obviously, the same thing applies to it: since it consists of `LinkNode<T>` it has to also accept a generic parameter of type `<T>`, so it cannot have built-in knowledge of the actual type of `<T>` either.

Therefore, you cannot suddenly introduce a method which has such knowledge. It does not make sense.  "It does not compute".

What you need to do instead is add this `print()` method of yours *elsewhere*, and make it accept a `LinkList<BoxClass>`.  Then, it will be able to view the `LinkNode`s as `LinkNode<BoxClass>`, and it will be able to invoke `linkNode.data.toString()`.

Comment: I don't think that I quite understand... So, does the problem lie within my Node? Are you saying that essentially, my Node class just doesn't know what to do with my `BoxClass` `method()`?. 

If so, does that mean that my LinkNode.h will have to have a `print()` method that accepts a `LinkList<BoxClass>` as a parameter which will in turn, allow me to call `toString()`?

Comment: @user3499789 A linked list is useless if you can't iterate through it using a `public` interface.  What if I want to do something else with each node in the list, other than print?  What if instead of print, I want to save the data to a file, or something more complex for each node in the list?  Are you going to know everything the user of the linked list class may want to do with the data in the list?  Of course not.  So your current implementation is incomplete -- it doesn't provide a way for the code from outside the linked list class to go through each node.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am saying, except for the "LinkNode.h" part.  The print() method does not belong to the LinkNode, nor to the LinkList.  It must go elsewhere.